# Ruby On Rails : I need some explanations about form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a RoR application. So i want to create a web form with select drop down type. I found the following code in a project. Here is a form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :key_words %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:skill_list, User::all_tags, :name, :name, {},{multiple: true}) %>
</div>
```

I create in User controller class :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
 def all_tags
    @tags = Tag.all

  end
end
```

Here is database :

[image]
1. I don't understand what is `User::all_tags` ?  Ok understood
2. I cannot see tags in my select drop down. What is missing ?

Comment: `all_tags` can be a class method that returns all tags from the database

Comment: in which class can i see it ?

Comment: you can see at `User` class. Note that this class is a user defined class and method. It is not a Rails core Class or method

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the context first, and then need to understand it.

You are passing: `User::all_tags, :name, :name`

`User::all_tags` returns you most probably an array/hash, and this array will be utilized to populate `collection_select`, but a general `option` tag has two things: 1) `value` that will exactly be sent to the server, and a piece of text that will be shown, but won't necessarily be sent to the server.

The first argument after `User::all_tags` determines what to have for `value`, and second argument decides what to have for that apparent text.

```
<option value="First argument goes here ">"Second argument">/option> # this isn't valid code
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me all_tags a method that placed in user class and have an array or hash containing the values
you can call that method like User.all_tags as well